# Calling a method in other class on same View Controller

Tags: objective-c

I am really messed up here. I have read few tutorials and examples but i just don't understand how to do it.

I have a View Controller with GamePlay class. On same View Controller I am having a sprite kit class. Now from SK class i want to call a method from GamePlay class that dismisses a View Controller. But I know that the I cannot do it with creating a new instance of class1. I want to cal a method from class1 that is already created and loaded.

Any help?

In sprite kit class i have imported GamePlay.h file and now I am calling a method end:

```
 -(void)endOfGame
 {
     GamePlay *gp = [[[GamePlay alloc]init];
     [gp end];

 }
```

In  GamePlay class I have method end that dismisses this View Controller

```
 -(void)end
 {
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

But this won't work. Because i am not calling the method form already created class, but I am creating a new instance of GamePlay class.

Comment: Could you paraphrase your question? Because it's really difficult to understand what are you asking for.

Comment: Generally, you can either (1) pass a reference to your `GamePlay` object into your SK object, so it can refer to it; or (2) have the SK object send a message to the view controller, and have the view controller send a message to the `GamePlay` object.

Comment: I dont understand. These are not separated view controllers. GamePlay class is a main class of the view controller and it is presenting SKView. SK class is presented on the same view controller. So passing data between view controllers is not helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit... unclear. But, I think I get what you're asking. In essence, "How do I get a reference to my `GamePlay` object into another class?"

There are a few ways to do this, depending on the exact relationships between the two classes. I'm not personally familiar with SpriteKit (yet), but you should be able to just add a property to your other class:

```
//MyOtherClass.h
#import "GamePlay.h"

@interface MyOtherClass : NSObject

@property GamePlay * gamePlay;

@end


//MyOtherClass.m
-(void)endOfGame
{
    [self.gamePlay end];
}

//Wherever you are creating/using MyOtherClass
MyOtherClass* myOtherClass = ...

myOtherClass.gamePlay = self; //or whatever
```